# Reaction request with axes for Node.js, problem in CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am creating a project where your back-end localhost:3333 is developed in node.js and the front-end in react localhost:3000.
When I go to access the API without any type of token or validation, it works perfectly, however when using token to validate accesses, there are some errors in CORS.

When I click on a button in the "Login" application to access the login, there is still no token, so I can make this request successfully, but in the next ones, where the token is requested, the following error occurs:

```
>Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3333/processo' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

>GET http://localhost:3333/cliente net::ERR_FAILED

>Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

My chrome network looks like this

```
>Request URL: http://localhost:3333/processo
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTk3MTc5MDQ0LCJleHAiOjE1OTc3ODM4NDR9.hsj3D1nMSuuHx-r2SofNH0zMiUKIPKeAun1sjccYi7I
Referer: http://localhost:3000/inicio
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

---

I've tried two things, the first was to add an extension to the chrome "Moesif Cors" it didn't work, it only works when I don't send Bearer.

And the other was trying to change from https to http. but it also didn't work.

how can i solve this? does this problem happen in my service? how do I configure cors to allow the token?

I will show below how my backend end node.js is configured.

**server.js**

```
import app from './app';

app.listen('3333');
```

**app.js**

```
import 'dotenv/config';

import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import Youch from 'youch';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import 'express-async-errors';
import routes from './routes';
import sentryConfig from './config/sentry';

import './database';

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.server = express();

    Sentry.init(sentryConfig);

    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
    this.exceptionHandler();
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.server.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
    this.server.use(express.json());
    this.server.use(
      '/files',
      express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tmp', 'uploads'))
    );
  }

  routes() {
    this.server.use(routes);
    this.server.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
  }

  exceptionHandler() {
    this.server.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        const errors = await new Youch(err, req).toJSON();

        return res.status(500).json(errors);
      }

      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    });
  }
}

export default new App().server;
```

---

now i will show how the call is on the front end where i have an api.js file

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getToken } from "./auth";

const api = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost:3333', 
});


api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
   const token = getToken();
   if (token) {
     config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
   }
   return config;
 });

export default api;
```

when I remove the header config, the requests work perfectly.

```
api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
   const token = getToken();
   if (token) {
     config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
   }
   return config;
 });
```

---

[EDIT]

I'm starting to think that the problem is the way I'm sending it from the front end and not from the back end

example of a call to the api

```
async listAll() {
    const result = await api.get(apiService);
    const list = result.data || [];
    this.setState({ list, listaFiltrada: list });
}
```

Comment: Enabling cors in your express should do. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Comment: cors will be helpful, as you can set a white/black-list of urls

Comment: Taking into account the app.js structure, where can I add the cors?

Comment: is it possible to do it manually as @hurricane instructed?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the [`cors`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware to Express?

Comment: added and it didn't work, it works only when I don't send the token

Answer (score 2):

If you try this request from a server or PostMan it would work. But since you are trying to make a request from the browser you need enable cors in your express server.

There are two simple way to achieve it;

Use cors library

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors());
```

or Write custom middleware. Manual solution for your case would be;

```
import 'dotenv/config';

import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import Youch from 'youch';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import 'express-async-errors';
import routes from './routes';
import sentryConfig from './config/sentry';

import './database';

class App {
  constructor() {
    this.server = express();
    this.enableCORS();
    Sentry.init(sentryConfig);
    
    this.middlewares();
    this.routes();
    this.exceptionHandler();
  }
  enableCORS(){
    this.server.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

      if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    });
  }

  middlewares() {
    this.server.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
    this.server.use(express.json());
    this.server.use(
      '/files',
      express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'tmp', 'uploads'))
    );
  }

  routes() {
    this.server.use(routes);
    this.server.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
  }

  exceptionHandler() {
    this.server.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        const errors = await new Youch(err, req).toJSON();

        return res.status(500).json(errors);
      }

      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    });
  }
}

export default new App().server;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer, I tried to do it manually, I added your code snippet before app.listen ('3333'); but the problem remains, should I put it elsewhere?

Comment: @EmiryMirella I would create new function which is called enableCors() and call it before middlewares(). And in the function I would call this.server.all(...)

Comment: I just tested it, and the same error continues. : /, it's like it had no effect

Comment: @EmiryMirella Can you try it with the edited version. I have added Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and '*' for URL.

Comment: I tried your edited method and it was not, continues has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. to make it easier, I tried it automatically. added, yarn add cors, and used this.server.use (cors); after this.server = express (); but it did not work

Comment: I tried using the edge browser, and the same error happens. without sending the token, it works, and when sending it does not.

Comment: calling the url through the browser, it works normal http: // localhost: 3333 / collaborator

Comment: I edited my question and put an "example" of how I'm calling the API

Comment: @EmiryMirella Please make a request using Postman and make sure the backend is running fine. If the backend is not the problem create another post for frontend.

Comment: @EmiryMirella It is good. So frontend has problem. Instead of interceptors try to use this one https://flaviocopes.com/axios-send-authorization-header/

Comment: Good afternoon, I tested the call just like you said but it also didn't work, the same error happens

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **create-react-app** project, try using the the proxy option in `package.json`

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3333"
```

Then you would replace URLs in the client like so

```js
axios.get('/') // maps to http://localhost:3333
axios.get('/api/anything') // maps to http://localhost:3333/api/anyting
```

Answer (score 0):

Install this on the nodejs side

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

config like this

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
app.use(cors())
 
app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
 
app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: added and it didn't work, it works only when I don't send the token